# $\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid \left|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)\right|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{(0,0)\right\}\cup\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1\neq\pm x_2\right\}$

Tags: continuity, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Problem 18 on p.194
> Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1,x_2):=\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ and $f(0,0):=0$.
> Let $c$ be an arbitrary real number.
> Then, $x_1\mapsto f(x_1,c)$ and $x_2\mapsto f(c,x_2)$ are continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
> Show that $f$ is not a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

> The author's solution:
> For example,  $$\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid \left|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)\right|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{(0,0)\right\}\cup\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1\neq\pm x_2\right\}$$ and this is not a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

I filled the gap of this answer as follows:

> If $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$, then $f(x_1,x_2)=0$.
> If $x_1=0$ and $x_2\neq 0$, then $f(x_1,x_2)=0$.
> If $x_1\neq 0$ and $x_2=0$, then $f(x_1,x_2)=0$.
> Let $x_1\neq 0$ and $x_2\neq 0$.
> Then $\left|f(x_1,x_2)\right|=\frac{|x_1||x_2|}{|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}+\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}}$.
> By a famous inequality,
> $$\frac{\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}+\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}}{2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}\cdot\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}}=1.$$
> So, $$\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}+\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}\geq 2.$$
> So, $$|f(x_1,x_2)|=\frac{1}{\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}+\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}}\leq\frac{1}{2}.$$
> And $|f(x_1,x_2)|=\frac{1}{\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}+\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}}=\frac{1}{2}$ if and only if $x_1=\pm x_2$.
>
> Therefore,  $$\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid \left|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)\right|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{(0,0)\right\}\cup\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1\neq\pm x_2\right\}$$ and this is not a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

My solution used the famous inequality about arithmetic mean and geometric mean.
But I don't want to use this inequality.
Please show the following equality without using the famous inequality $$\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid \left|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)\right|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{(0,0)\right\}\cup\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1\neq\pm x_2\right\}.$$

Comment: Although this is in essence reproving AM/GM, your calculus argument is definite overkill. $(x_1-x_2)^2\ge 0$, so $x_1^2 + x_2^2 \ge 2x_1x_2$, with equality holding iff $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$.
Then, $g'(x) = \frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$.
If $-1<x<1$, then $g'(x)>0$.
If $x<-1$ or $1<x$, then $g'(x)<0$.
If $x=1$ or $x=-1$, then $g'(x)=0$.
And $g(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $g(-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

If $x_1=0$, then $f(x_1,x_2)=0$.
Let $x_1\neq 0$.
Then, $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}=\frac{\frac{x_2}{x_1}}{1+\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)^2}=g\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)$.
$|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)|=|f(x_1,x_2)|=\left|g\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}$.
And $\left|g\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{2}$ if and only if $x_1=x_2$ or $x_1=-x_2$.
So, the following equality holds:
$$\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid \left|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)\right|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{(0,0)\right\}\cup\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1\neq\pm x_2\right\}.$$